# extract a value from a string using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to extract a value from a string using regex. The string looks like this:

```
<faultcode>&lt;![CDATA[900015The new password is not long enough. PasswordMinimumLength is 6.]]&gt;</faultcode>
```

I am trying to diplay only the error message to end user.

Comment: And, what value are you looking for?

Comment: Which value are you trying to extract?

Comment: Is there a chance you're parsing XML yourself instead of using a tool?

Comment: i need to parse xml myself without using any tool.

Comment: Is <![CDATA[ always appears in start of your string? and ]]> in end of string?

Comment: If this is the only string, do it by hand. I suspect you mean "strings", and then 2+ samples would be a lot better. Plus expected result.

Comment: i need to show following string to end user "The new password is not long enough. PasswordMinimumLength is 6."

Comment: Note that you can _edit_ a question.

Comment: I hope there's a good reason for this, because it looks pretty stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Since you probably want everything `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` this should fit:

```
<!\[CDATA\[(.+?)\]\]>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only sensible thing is to load it into an `XElement` (or XDocument, XmlDocument) and extract the Value from the CDATA element.

```
XElement e = XElement.Parse(xmlSnippet);
string rawMsg = (e.FirstNode as XCData).Value;
string msg = rawMsg.Substring("900015".Length);
```

Comment: Assuming the `&lt;` is actually `<` in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to correspond with the question edit:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(yourString);
var allText = xml.Value;
var stripLeadingNumbers = Regex.Match(xml.Value, @"^\d*(.*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, and foremost, using [regex to parse XML / HTML is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/492405).

Now, by error message I assume you mean the text, not including the numbers. An expression like so would probably do the trick:

```
\<([^>]+)\>&lt;!\[CDATA\[\d*(.*)\]\]&gt;\</\1\>
```

The error message will be in the second group. This will work with the sample that you have given, but I'd sooner use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) or [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to parse it. If you are using C#, there really isn't a good reason to not use either of those classes.